# Wordpress query posts by custom post type not workng

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-taxonomy, customization, loop

I'm trying to display the featured images of my custom post type of 'instrument'

I created the custom post type using the plugin 'Custom Post Type UI'

The query seems to work, but the problem is that it does not seem to loop - only the most recent post is displayed.

However, when I try this same code but querying all posts with a category of instruments, normal posts with the category will show, but not my custom posts with the category added.

This is the code:

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=instrument');
           while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>

                            <div class="col-sm-2">

                                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">   

                                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?>

                                </a>

                            </div><!--.col-sm-2-->

       <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad use of Query you may [look at this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)

In this case use a secondary query with your own instance of WP Query. query_posts() is not recommanded here cause [it overrides the main query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/).

```
<?php $args = array(
    'post_type'           => 'instrument',
    'post_status'         => 'publish',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
);
$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="col-sm-2">

            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

                <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' ); ?>

            </a>

        </div><!--.col-sm-2-->

    <?php endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
endif; ?>
```